# Parsley parser under python 3.4 is not working

Tags: python, parsing, package, peg

I'm newbie in Python, but I want to parse some text files (VCard *.vcf), and I've stumbled upon Parsley from Allen Short. However it seems to not working under new Python3.4, is there working version?
I have version from [pypi.python.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Parsley)
BTW: Parsley is bad name because of many other projects with this name...
There is example from readme...

```
from parsley import makeGrammar
exampleGrammar = """
ones = '1' '1' -> 1
twos = '2' '2' -> 2
stuff = (ones | twos)+
"""
Example = makeGrammar(exampleGrammar, {})
g = Example("11221111")
result = g.stuff()
print (result)
```

After run it returns:

```
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

EDIT 2014.06.12 
I've found solution, pip installed old version of Parsley. There is ?fork on github which is working under Python 3.X https://github.com/vsajip/parsley

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to generate a VCard parser or to use a VCard parser? If the latter you'd better use an existing python VCard parser, for instance vobject https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vobject

Comment: Thank's I didn't find this parser (there is some genetical format with the same vcf extension), but I want to start with something easy and then go for more advanced tasks (some data mining from old papers OCR->cleanup->parse).